# .NET enum.HasFlag() bug?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, flags, enum-flags

I'm using the following .NET 4.5.2 code:

```
if (this.ContainsFocus && keyData == (Keys.Tab|Keys.Shift))
{ ... }
```

Why is the expression true when ContainsFocus (bool = true) and keyData (System.Windows.Forms.Keys) is Keys.O | Keys.Shift?

As you can see the breakpoint is hit:

[image: breakpointscreenshot]

with this values:

[image: watchscreenshot]

A workaround for this bug (?!) is:

```
if (this.ContainsFocus && (int)keyData == (int)(Keys.Tab|Keys.Shift))
{ ... }
```

Comment: which control event do you use?

Comment: [Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx): "Do not use the values in this enumeration for combined bitwise operations. The values in the enumeration are not mutually exclusive."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Ignoring the line near the top: `This enumeration has a FlagsAttribute attribute that allows a bitwise combination of its member values.` lol probably an auto-doc fail from having the `FlagsAttribute` applied.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - yes, I do find the application of the `FlagsAttribute` to that enumeration... troublesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `HasFlag` does not have a bug. Unfortunately, the .NET `FlagsAttribute` is all or nothing and `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` is defined in such a way that only `Keys.Modifiers` may be used as flags.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> The Keys class contains constants for processing keyboard input. The
>   members of the Keys enumeration consist of a key code and a set of
>   modifiers combined into a single integer value. In the Win32
>   application programming interface (API) a key value has two halves,
>   with the high-order bits containing the key code (which is the same as
>   a Windows virtual key code), and the low-order bits representing key
>   modifiers such as the SHIFT, CONTROL, and ALT keys.

As a result, you can check any of the modifiers (`Keys.Shift`, `Keys.Alt`, `Keys.Control`) with `HasFlag`, but nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug of `HasFlag`, it is how it work.
Suppose we have the following values:

```
var a = (Keys.Tab | Keys.Shift);
var b = (Keys.O | Keys.Shift);
```

Now we analyze the bits of these values (when we cast them to integers):

> a: 1000000000100**000**1
>   b: 1000000000100**111**1

If we call `a.HasFlag(b)` we get `false` because not every 1-bit from *b* is a 1 in *a* too. But if we call `b.HasFlag(a)` we get `true` because every 1-bit of *a* is set in *b* too.

That's why you need to compare the values with `a==b` or with `a.HasFlag(b) && b.HasFlag(a)`. Then it will work properly.